# Fixed Nav on ios moves when horizontally scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have created a site which scrolls horizontally through the sections and is responsive. The problem is that on ios when you scroll right to the second section the fixed header starts to move off the page. Scroll right again and it will move a little more (almost as if a negative margin is being applied with every section)

I do not know what is going wrong as it seems to be working fine when I re size the browser its just a problem on the iphone.

[You can view the problem here](http://www.4nihomes.co.uk/m/Example5/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove width: 100vw; in the header styles and replace with 100%? I believe some iOS's are a bit buggy with this.

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the header to span across all four sections.. and the menu icon to only appear on the last section.

Comment: @maeve i see... okay, maybe wrap a containment div around the content. set its width and overflow hidden. This will leave your header separate from the content, allowing the header to be 100% width of the browser.

http://codepen.io/bajere/pen/zvEJNL

Comment: Thanks Bajere, but this didnt work the header still moved when sliding to the side and also caused issues with the positioning of the sections

Comment: @maeve odd, it's a simple thing, as I've done a similar build. I cannot seem to get the correct view on my iPhone to test it. It's like the view port meta is not set. You can plug your iPhone into your Mac and then use safari to debug the page. It should tell you everything you need to know... I would do it for you, but I'm away from computer until tomorrow, sorry

Comment: @maeve Im inspecting the site in an iPhone6 plus with devtools, its looking like this: http://cl.ly/image/272x1P07470w

You are also setting the sections to be 375px wide, which is off for responsive build. Are you able to post this on fiddle or codepen? Myself and others might be able to help you easier?

Comment: Hi Bajere, I don't have access to a mac to debug the browser on my iphone, I've posted it on codepen, Hope this helps http://codepen.io/maeve/pen/JYOPKo

Comment: @maeve Your pen seems to work as intended on desktop, but it crashes the iPhone... i guess its not compatible.

My iPhone is still rendering the original site you posted incorrectly. What iPhone and OS are you using?

In any situation, having this in the media query for mobile should work though. Unless JS is changing it, and from what i can tell its not. It should force the header to the top left at all times!

`header {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    color: #0054a4;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position: fixed;
}`

Comment: I am using an iphone 5 and have updated it to version 9.0.2.. again the header being made 100% makes it span across the 4 sections

Comment: I think I have fixed the viewport problem

Comment: @maeve great. that might help things. If you update your original link, we can have a play around in the dev tools!

Comment: 1/2

@maeve, I have managed to take a look now you fixed the viewport. It seems that plugin you are using forces the HTML element to have a width of 1500px, which is the 4x375px (the width of your sections). When you swipe, you are effectively moving the entire site along. This includes the header. For some reason, mobiles are not happy with this. I am assuming its down to the view port settings, [i just found this page](http://trgraglia.github.io/jquery.horizonScroll.js/demo/index.html) , and edited it to have a fixed header. It worked on desktop, but failed on mobile.

Comment: 2/2

@maeve . The plugin is nearly a year old, so it might of been abandoned. Might be worth looking for a new plugin that does what you want. You may find something good here: http://www.unheap.com/section/user-interface/scrolling/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will have a look at this

Comment: @maeve no problem, sorry i couldnt give you a quick fix